# jQuery Pan & Zoom or Magnify script with ability of hotspot or image map link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation

Im creating a super simple 'app' for facebook were users will have to locate a character from within a detailed illustration (wheres waldo style).

I want people to be able to Zoom and Pan (like google maps) but also have the ability to click on the character once they find it and have a popup or redirect to the next page.

Does anyone know of a script that can do this? I have found a few zoom tools but you cant click or create hotspots, same goes with the zoom + pan tools. I found this one which is quite nice: http://www.dimin.net/software/panojs/#Demos

Hoping someone knows of something that will work for me.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up just using a good old html map with a redirect. Thanks all!